# Xcode: Error message: This app could not be installed at this time. Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path

Tags: xcode, build, compiler-errors

When I try to build the app on the simulator or device, I have an error message on the first launch:

**This app could not be installed at this time.**

> Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path
>   /Users/OlostA/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/25D8061D-0E37-4EE6-8CF8-24C981141613/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.i1VdF1/extracted/Payload/GMP_app_ios
>   AppStore.app